# How is code splitting hiding parts of the app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, code-splitting

If I am building a React frontend app and there's let's say an admin panel and parts of the app that only people with a paid account should see I was told to use code splitting, this way parts of the app are only served when you get to that point.

But does it really hide anything?

You can still see the list of chunks in the `main.js` and just fetch them anyway?

Summarizing from the comments below:

Some kind of server-side solution seems to be required to prevent getting certain chunks from served unless authorized with the server but I cannot find any handy roll yourself guides in the Internet. My React app gets served via nginx, so I cannot do this without creating a separate server.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you correctly implement it, it would not be possible.

Libraries like React Router v4 will not load them in the `main.js` file but these classes will instead be loaded via their own components. Server side protection will prevent fetching these components from people without the paid account you were talking about.

Comment: The OP should also be aware that while this is a nice practice, this not a trustable safety mechanism for discerning from paid/non-paid as it's easily exploitable from anyone that has access to the chunk file PATH

Comment: They're not loaded correct, but I can lookup the chunk filenames and retrieve them.

Comment: @enapupe that's what I thought. Is there a good guide how to deal with this? Is the real solution limited to using some react Serverside?

Comment: Simply splitting code and displaying the specific parts to only those who are a paid user will indeed not be very secure. That's why I would recommend protected routes.

Comment: @Craws Is Protected Routes the right keyword here? This just means that you cannot access the routes without authentication. I have that set in place, I meant more: someone could snoop through the JS files and understand the mechanics of your app to find attack vectors, I want to hide that content, not serve it at all unless you authenticate. I can't think of a solution that doesn't involve backend logic. My React app currently gets served via nginx only

Comment: I think of ways to roll this myself, it would mostly be: create two separate react apps, one for the auth part and the other one for the restricted content and let a simple server handle serving the right app but I am surprised there's no plain in-React ecosystem solution, guide, blog post… or maybe I haven't found it yet.

Comment: @Mahoni Unfortunately, I can not help you with this. But I understand what you mean. I'd recommend to search for something that does not send the components when you are not logged in. This will prevent the user from having any information about the protected pages at all.

Comment: It does sound like you need to move to a some form of a server-generated system, even if a simple one, if paid-user security is a requirement.